# How to politely ask for clearer explanation when getting lost in workplace?

Tags: expressions, email

As a second language speaker, I always concern if my interpersonal reaction is proper and polite enough.

For instance,sometimes I got some email from other native colleagues who wrote in phrases or slang that lost me. So far I had no good idea to properly say I didn't get it well and could you please make it clearer.

So I replied as 'sorry ***, I didn't get you well but if you meant that ... I can do ...'

Could someone please suggest some more better replies for this case?

Cheers

Comment: Don't be so rash in accepting my answer. Somebody might give you a better one!

Comment: Honestly, your answer is good enough for me to put in my daily work. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are formal and informal ways of saying it. **"Sorry"** is one of those words that mean that you are *"sorry for not having understood what was said or done"*, used mainly to bring somebody's attention to the statement.

- Pardon me, could you please explain what you meant by saying ... (*Formal*)

You could use **"Excuse me"** or **"I beg your pardon"** instead.

Your reply, *"Sorry, I didn't get you well but if you meant that ... I can do ..."* is good and polite.

More possible ways:

- Sorry, didn't catch what you said
- I'm sorry but I didn't understand what you said